# Error occurs after publishing website

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hello everyone,
               I'm managing a website written in asp.net mvc4. However i made certain changes to the layout and css styles which i wanted to publish so as to update the present site. Before publishing everything worked fine and when i was in the process  of publishing i made sure that i didnt touch the web.config file i only checked the files i want to updatee which was majorly an Html and css changes.

After publishing and i tried to login, i started getting an error saying

```
Error
An error occurred while processing your request.
```

Please help me out. I can supply any other info that can help me resolve this problem.

when i tried the one i had on my localhost i got this error

```
You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.

Source Error: 


Line 36:         public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
Line 37:         {
Line 38:             if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
Line 39:             {
Line 40:                 //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

Source File: c:\Users\IBN HAMZA\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Zedvance\Zedvance\Controllers\AccountController.cs    Line: 38 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: You must call the "WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection" method before you call any other method of the "WebSecurity" class. This call should be placed in an _AppStart.cshtml file in the root of your site.]
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.VerifyInitialized() +50
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.VerifyProvider() +36
   WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Login(String userName, String password, Boolean persistCookie) +14
   Zedvance.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginModel model, String returnUrl) in c:\Users\IBN HAMZA\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Zedvance\Zedvance\Controllers\AccountController.cs:38
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +147
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +182
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9657896
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Set `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in your web.config to check full error

Comment: @Vsevolod should i do that on the live site or on my localhost ?

Comment: if it works on your localhost site and doesn't on your live site, then do it there. If it doesn't work on your local site then you should get the YSOD or see the exception in your VS

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin ive updated my question above with the error and stack trace that showed up when i tried the localhost version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the error that you are getting, the problem seems to be the fact that you are called `WebSecurity` before initializing the connection.

Edit the file that throws that error like this:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
    }
```

Comment: sorry i dont understand "The only way to fix it really is to redeploy the whole website, with the exception if your web.config file". Wont that affect the database?

Comment: Isn't your database remotely located? Like SQL Server?

Comment: Please if i effect this change what effect would it have, because this site is not a new site it has been around for long, hope there would not be any data loss. And will it solve the problem? Would People have to start re-registering?

Comment: Do you use an external database? If yes, there's no chance the database will be affected.

Comment: By external database do you mean a database on sql server? and not a local DB. If thats what you mean then Yes, we use an external database.